# How to trigger just part of the onchange of a form element from other code?

Tags: javascript, forms, onchange

It's easy enough to trigger the onchange function of a form element from javascript:

```
element.onchange();
```

But say the onchange is something like this:

```
<input id=foo type=checkbox onChange="function1(argA, argB); function2(argC);">
```

Is it possible to trigger just the "function2(argC)" part, if it's present?

A crude approach might be to somehow get the onchange function as text, inspect it to see if function2 is in there, and if so, feed "function2(argC)" to an eval.

this code:

```
var thatInput = document.getelementbyid('foo');
alert(thatInput.onchange);
```

yields

```
function onchange(event) {
    function1(argA, argB); function2(argC);); 
}
```

in the alert box, but I couldn't figure out how to get that as a string to manipulate.  thatInput.onchange has a name property which is just "onchange"; and it has a length of 1.  None of that seems useful.

Comment: If you already know that you want to call function2() why don't you call it directly? It must be global if it's called from an inline html event handler, and argC must be a global variable too...

Comment: Try getting the attribute `onChange`. I m not sure, try using jquery `$(ele).attr("onChange");`. See what you get, you might get it as string.

Comment: In the context, it's unpredictable whether function2 will be part of checkbox foo's onchange, and what argC will be. Also it's not jquery, alas.

Comment: What I was trying to do was have the onchange of one form element, after doing its own thing, trigger part of the onchange of another form element.  There is a back-end solution, of course, where "function2(argC)" is written into the onchange of the first form element when appropriate.  But in my particular situation, it would be much easier to handle it on the client side in javascript if it were possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap those two function calls in a parent function, and use an optional param to determine whether `function2` should be called or not:

```
function handleChange(useFunction1, useFunction2) {
    if ( useFunction1 ) {
        function1(argA, argB);
    }

    if ( useFunction2 ) {
        function2(argC);
    }
}

// Calls function1 without calling function2
<input id=foo type=checkbox onChange="handleChange(true, false);">

// Calls function2 without calling function1
<input id=foo type=checkbox onChange="handleChange(false, true);">

// Calls both functions
<input id=foo type=checkbox onChange="handleChange(true, true);">
```

Or, if you'd prefer to have both functions be called by default UNLESS you manually specify otherwise:

```
function handleChange(useFunction1, useFunction2) {
    if ( useFunction1 === true || useFunction1 === undefined ) {
        function1(argA, argB);
    }

    if ( useFunction2 === true || useFunction2 === undefined ) {
        function2(argC);
    }
}

// Calls both functions by default
<input id=foo type=checkbox onChange="handleChange();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not trigger function2 directly.

Example:

```
    $("#foo").on('change',function(){
        if($(this).attr('checked')){  // If is checked
           function1();
           function2();
          }else{
           function2();
      }
   })
```

Comment: function2 should only be called if it's present in the onchange of foo.  It won't always be present; or it might even be present multiple times with different arguments.  For my particular problem, any client-side solution would require parsing the onchage code attached to foo, to see what is in there.

Comment: `jQuery !== javascript`, IMHO answers should stick to pure HTML/JS given the original question's code seems to be sans-jQuery